# Filtering set in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got the following models.

```
class FAQCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)       

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class FAQ(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(FAQCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

Within my template, I'd like to be able to show a category title ONLY if there are FAQs that have that category (already satisfied with the code below) and at least one FAQ that has that category has a answer that is not equal to None or "" (not sure how to do this).  So far, I have the following code:

```
        {% if category.faq_set.all|length > 0 %}

                {{category.title}}

        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a template filter to achieve answer check:

```py
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def has_answer(queryset):
    return queryset.filter(answer__isnull=False).exclude(answer__exact='').exists()
```

Then you can use this filter in the template as:

```
{% if category.faq_set.all|has_answer %}
```

Sorry for the first answer which not covering has_answer feature.

Comment: This doesn't actually check to see if any of the faqs in the set have an answer filled in.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sorry for not covering all the questions, I didn't noticed that part.

Comment: By the way, you can improve filter with the conditions you need.